# after I Embedded a Google Drive folder on my web page is there any way to get number of files in to my web page?

Tags: html, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-drive-shared-drive

Exaple:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDER-ID#grid" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>
```

I want to show number of files in side my google drive folders automatic in HTML page

Like

```
<p> {number of files} Files</p>
```

output should be something like this

```
10 Files
```

or

```
20 Files
```

so I want that number change whenever I add a new file to that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

You can't.

**Long answer**

You can access an element inside an `iframe` of your page with javascript something like this:

```
 window.frames['frameid'].contentDocument.getElementById('elementid')
```

however, for security reasons, the "same origin policy"  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy applies. So, this method will not work in your case, because the domain in one origin the one of the `iframe` (`drive.google.com`) is not the same as the domain a different origin, your page.